# Jquery Text Slide in Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-ui

I want to make text animation like this slide in from left. There are three text fields
Sports Cargo Bag 
$14 
Sale $25

I want these text to be set from jquery and slide in from the left like this [link](http://platform.mediamind.com/Eyeblaster.Preview.Web/AdPreview.aspx?reportinteractions=0&adid=21081001)
. This is my code [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uk72R/2/), i have set these headtext but i want to use jquery method to set these texts

**html**

```
 <div id="mainContainer">

    <div id="logdo">
     <img  src="http://i.share.pho.to/7346a9ca_o.gif"/>
    </div>
         <div id="images">
        <img id="introImg" src="http://i.share.pho.to/9064dfe4_o.jpeg"/></div>
    <div id="headlineText">
        <p id="headline1Txt" ></p>
        <p id="headline2Txt" ></p>
   <p id="headline3Txt" ></p>


    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="ctaBtn" type="button">SHOP NOW</button>

        </div>
```

**css**

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}



#mainContainer{ text-align: center;
width:160px;
    height:600px;
 box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    border:5px solid #BACAE4;

    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;

}

#images{
    position:absolute;
    top:200px;
    left:3px;
    right:1286px;
    Width:130px;
    height:152px;

}
#introImg{
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    left:7px;
    right:11px;

}
#headlineText p
{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
   top:60px;
    left:-120px; 
Width:120px;
    height:269px;
 line-height:1.0;
    overflow:hidden;

}

#ctaBtn{
        position:absolute;
    top:540px;
    left:26px;
    right:0px;
    Width:106px;
    height:28px;

}
```

Comment: When do you want it to slide in? On page load, on click, on hover?

Comment: on page load can you see the demo/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest method:

Replace all our current javascript in your fiddle with `$("#mainContainer").hide().show('slide');`.

If you want you can use `.delay(500)` to make it wait a bit before the animation: `$("#mainContainer").hide().delay(500).show('slide');`

Comment: can you see this http://platform.mediamind.com/Eyeblaster.Preview.Web/AdPreview.aspx?reportinteractions=0&adid=21081001 i want like that but i want to set text from jquery dynamically

Comment: i have updated my code http://jsfiddle.net/uk72R/2/ . I want text to appear from jquery method here i have used my own text fields i want to set headtext using jquery